# Transaction doesn't work in aspectj

Tags: aspectj, spring-transactions

I have the aspect(see below) which should log actions(create, update, delete) in db. Depends on action logging happens in a preProcess or postProcess method. I shouldn't log anything if some fail happens through these actions. I.e. if create didn't happened, then there is no need to logging it.

I tried to tested it. I throw RunTimeException in the join point and expect that there is no new log in db. Unfortunately, new log is saved in spite of exception in the join point.

Aspect:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    @Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Around("@annotation(Loggable)")
    @Transactional
    public void saveActionMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Loggable m = ms.getMethod().getAnnotation(Loggable.class);
        LoggingStrategy strategy = appContext.getBean(m.strategy());
        Object argument = joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        strategy.preProcess(argument);
        joinPoint.proceed();
        strategy.postProcess(argument);
    }
}
```

TestApplicationConfig:

```xml
<context:spring-configured/>
    <import resource="applicationConfig-common.xml"/>
    <import resource="applicationConfig-security.xml"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <util:map id="testValues">
        <entry key="com.exadel.mbox.test.testSvnFile" value="${svnFolder.configPath}${svnRoot.file[0].fileName}"/>
        <entry key="com.exadel.mbox.test.testCommonRepositoryPath" value="${svnRoot.commonRepositoryPath}"/>
        <entry key="com.exadel.mbox.test.testMailFile" value="${mailingList.configPath}"/>
    </util:map>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.exadel.report.common" />

    <!-- Jpa Repositories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.exadel.report.common.dao" />

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                          transaction-manager="txManager" mode="aspectj"/>

    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Data Source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="exviewer-test"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

**[Update]**

LoggingStrategy:

```java
public interface LoggingStrategy {
    public void preProcess(Object obj);
    public void postProcess(Object obj);
}
```

BaseLoggingStrategy:

```java
public class BaseLoggingStrategy implements LoggingStrategy {
    @Override
    public void preProcess(Object obj) {}

    @Override
    public void postProcess(Object obj) {}
}
```

UpdateProcessStrategy:

```java
@Service
public class UpdateProcessStrategy extends BaseLoggingStrategy {
    @Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    DeviceService deviceService;
    private Device currentDevice;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void preProcess(Object obj) {
        currentDevice = (Device) obj;
        Device previousDevice = deviceService.getById(currentDevice.getId());
        String deviceDataBeforeUpdate = deviceService.getDeviceDetailsInJSON(previousDevice);
        String deviceDataAfterUpdate = deviceService.getDeviceDetailsInJSON(currentDevice);

        String login = userService.getCurrentUser().getLogin();
        String actionMessage = LoggingMessages.DEVICE_UPDATE.name();

        loggingService.save(
                new Logging(
                        login,
                        actionMessage,
                        deviceDataBeforeUpdate,
                        deviceDataAfterUpdate,
                        new Date())
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcess(Object obj) {}
}
```

Class intercepted by aspcet:

```java
@Service
public class DeviceService {
    @Loggable(value = LoggingMessages.DEVICE_CREATE, strategy = CreateProcessStrategy.class)
    @Transactional
    public void create(Device device) {
        createOrUpdate(device);
    }

    @Loggable(value = LoggingMessages.DEVICE_UPDATE, strategy = UpdateProcessStrategy.class)
    @Transactional
    public void update(Device device) {
        createOrUpdate(device);
    }

    private void createOrUpdate(Device device) {
        deviceRepository.save(device);        
    } 

    @Loggable(value = LoggingMessages.DEVICE_REMOVE, strategy = RemoveProcessStrategy.class)
    public void remove(Long deviceId) {
        deviceRepository.delete(deviceId);
    }
}
```

Loggable annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Loggable {
    LoggingMessages value();
    Class<? extends LoggingStrategy> strategy();
}
```

Log for update action contains:
id, created_dtm, action(DEVICE_UPDATE), device_data_before_action_on_the_device(in json format), device_data_after_action_on_the_device(in json format), created_by.

Comment: Please also post the code for the `LoggingStrategy` and also the target class intercepted by the aspect, then also maybe some log output so as to give us the full picture. You only describe the crucial parts in plain prose, but your prose is too ambiguous to be understood clearly without the code. The `Loggable` annotation code would also be nice.

Comment: I've added all the mentioned stuff.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem: Within your advice you call `preProcess()` before `proceed()`, so it should be clear that something is logged before the actual exception in the joinpoint occurs. I can see that even without test-running your code. If you want to change that, you need to change the advice or the way you do logging in general. As it is, the code does just what you tell it to. Or do you have another problem? You still have not posted any details about what was logged vs. what you expect to be logged.

Comment: I log data about actions applied to different devices, i.e. device was created, updated or removed. But, I wouldn't like to log it if device is not created(updated or removed) actually.
I thought if all three methods:
preProcess, proceed and postProcess
will be part of one transaction it will decide my problem.
Maybe my understanding of transaction is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:*** Actually I am not a Spring expert, maybe someone else can help you out here. My field of expertise it AspectJ, which is how I found your question.

Anyway, you have two issues here:

- `@Transactional` annotation on your aspect's advice `LoggingAspect.saveActionMessage(..)`. Actually I have no idea if this works at all (I found no example using `@Transactional` on an aspect method/advice on the web, but maybe I searched in the wrong way) because declarative transaction handling in Spring is implemented via proxy-based technology, just like Spring AOP. Read the [chapter 12 about transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) in the Spring manual for further details, especially [chapter 12.5.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained). I am pretty sure you will find a way to do what you want there.
- Nested transactions, because e.g. `UpdateProcessStrategy.preProcess(..)` is called by the very advice which is meant to be transactional, but is declared `@Transactional` too. So you have a transaction within a transaction. How Spring handles this, I have no idea, but maybe this [tutorial about Spring transaction propagation](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-propagation-tutorial) contains enlightening details.

The Spring manual lists several means to implement transactional behaviour: programmatically, declaratively via annotations, XML-based `<tx:advice>` stuff and so forth. I don't know which way is the best for you, I merely wanted to provide some general hints.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer to you on the eve of the new year.
Unfortunately, I didn't find out a solution of my problem. But, I find your answer useful. Thank you!
I'll let you know if I solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can share a little GitHub repo, then someone here can reproduce your problem and help you find a solution.