# implementing aop..java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I am fairly new to Spring AOP. trying to implement AOP in my project. when i run the following code, I get this error. response really appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:203)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:189)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:167)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
```

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Authenticator {
    boolean byPassAuthentication() default false;
}
```

```java
@Aspect
public class PointcutDefinition {   
    @Pointcut("within(com.test.services..*)")
    public void authenticator() {}
}
```

```java
@Aspect
public class AccountLoggingAspect {
    @Before(value = "com.test.aop.PointcutDefinition.authenticator() && @annotation(auth)")
    public void authenticatorlogging(Authenticator auth) {
        System.out("test");
    }
}
```

```java
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Aspect
public class AspectAuditor {
    @Pointcut("within(com.test..*)")
    public void auditPtCut() {}

    @Before(value = "auditPtCut() && @annotation(log)")
    public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint jp, AuditLog log) {
        if (log.enable())
            Audit.startTask(jp.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="loggingAspect" 
    class="com.test.aop.AccountLoggingAspect">
</bean>
    <bean id="loggingAspectAuditor" 
    class="com.test.aop.AspectAuditor">
</bean>
```

now added this code to the xml..and now getting different error

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="loggingAspect" 
    class="com.test.aop.AccountLoggingAspect">
</bean>
    <bean id="loggingAspectAuditor" 
    class="com.test.aop.AspectAuditor">
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="com.test.aop.PointcutDefinition()" advice-ref="tx-advice"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="tx-advice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error can't bind type name 'com.test.aop'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to change this

```xml
<aop:advisor pointcut="com.test.aop.PointcutDefinition()" advice-ref="tx-advice"/>
```

to that

```xml
<aop:advisor pointcut="com.test.aop.PointcutDefinition.authenticator()" advice-ref="tx-advice"/>
```

This should fix the syntax error.

As for making an aspect or advice transactional in Spring AOP, I do not know if it is possible because I am not a Spring user, see also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27621933/1082681).